# How to add UNION ALL programmatically in a loop?

Tags: laravel

I need to construct a query of the following structure:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM table
WHERE
...
GROUP BY
...
UNION ALL

SELECT 
...
FROM table
WHERE
...
GROUP BY
...
UNION ALL

SELECT 
...
FROM table
WHERE
...
GROUP BY
...
.. and so on..
```

I get some data in an array, then I iterate it in a `foreach` loop where I construct each `SELECT` individually followed by a `UNION ALL` (except the last).

But I am not able to find a way to add that `UNION ALL` after every `SELECT` (Except for the last one):

```
$query = DB::table('table');
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $query->.. // construct the SELECT

    $query->unionAll($query); // does not work
}
```

How can I do it?

Update: Some more accurate code of what I'm using:

```
$query = DB::table('table');

foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $info) {
            $query->addSelect($key);
        }
    }

    $query->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE...)");
    $query->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE...)");

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $info) {
            $query->where($key, "=", $value);
        }
    }

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {        
        $query->addSelect($key);     
    } 

    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {        
        $query->groupBy($key);     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `unionAll` would need to take a new instance of the query builder each time.

You'd either need to set up the initial query outside of the loop or put a check inside the look to set the variable e.g.:

```
$query = null;

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!$query) {
        $query = DB::table($item['table'])
            ->where(...) // whatever else you would use to build up the query for the array
        ; 
        
        continue;
    }

    $query->unionAll(
        DB::table($item['table'])
            ->where(...) // Again, whatever else you would use to build up the query
    );
}

$results = $query->get();
```

Comment: It is really close, but from some reason in my case it changes the table name to `temp_table`. Note that it's not `$item['table']`. In my case I am using the same table in this `UNION` so you can hardcode the same table name there like `DB::table('table')`

Comment: @B.DLiroy I had put `$item['table']` as an example. Please can you update your question with the code your actually using :)

Comment: Sorry about that :D, added the code. Each iteration in the outer `foreach` is supposed to build a single `SELECT` (currently it does build the `SELECT`s correctly but without `UNION ALL`s)

Comment: @B.DLiroy Where's the base query where the queries inside the loop are added with `unionAll()`?

Comment: I could not find a way to make it work so I omitted it here. What I provided is the way I construct each SELECT, but I don't know how to add that union all correctly after each one

Comment: @B.DLiroy Like I've shown in my answer, each query has to be it's own instance of the query builder. You then use `unionAll` to add each subsequent instance to the first instance.

Comment: thanks, even with a new instance it was hard to find a way to write this query. It ended up doing `select from select...` and stuff like that. I ended up using raw sql query and bindings using `DB::select($sql_query, $bindings);`. From now on I will not try to convert complex queries to query builder anymore.